# Retrieving the parent URI of a BluePrinted component based on the URI of a child component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Does anyone know how can I find the URI of a parent Component based on the URI of a shared or localized component in a child publication in SDL Tridion using the Core Service?

Comment: Please define parent. Is it the first local copy of an item, or the very top parent. Do you know id of parent publication?

Comment: Pretty confusing terminology: a Component's parent is a Folder. So what are you really trying to get? The answers below assume you are looking for the same Component in a parent Blueprinted Publication...

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I guess the whole idea of the question was explanation of BluePrinted Publication...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's is simpler approach than the one that Nuno is proposing and you don't need to reference any dlls

```
var parentComponentid = ClientAdmin.GetTcmUri(component.Id, component.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository.IdRef, null);
```

`GetTcmUri` method is good for getting any TcmUris - just pass publication id you want your item in and Id of item in current publication. This way you can also find ID of a given item in particular child publication

Comment: What is CLientAdmin in this case?

Comment: It's just your CoreService client

Comment: This worked. I used the following code: session.Client.GetTcmUri(componentId, childComponent.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository.IdRef, null);

Comment: This indeed works, however the performance of this approach is not great. It will do a round-trip to the server for each call of GetTcmUri

Comment: Assume Component A is created in Publication PubX and shared with Publication PubY. If Component A is localized in Publication PubY, owning repository of localized Component A is PubY not PubX.

Comment: Yes you are right but Localizing is not an option in our case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ComponentData.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository.IdRef` to get the TcmUri of the publication that "owns" that component. This is the first publication "going up" where the component is either created or localized.

Then you can use something like this to get you the component Uri in the right context:

```cs
internal string GetUriInBlueprintContext(string itemId, string publicationId)
{
    if (TcmUri.UriNull == itemId)
        return null;
    TcmUri itemUri = new TcmUri(itemId);
    TcmUri publicationUri = new TcmUri(publicationId);
    TcmUri inContext = new TcmUri(itemUri.ItemId, itemUri.ItemType, publicationUri.ItemId);
    return inContext.ToString();
}
```

The `TcmUri` class is part of the Tridion.Common.dll which you can reference from your project too.

Comment: Question was about CoreService